# anchor links in emails not working after visiting once

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

So this question has been asked before, but the javascript solution doesn't work for me if I am simply emailing links to members. Here is an example of what I am talking about. I run a social network. When, for example, a user comments on another users profile, I want to email the user who isn't logged in and provide them a link to see the comment. Usually the link would be an onpage link with a # along with an id (example

The first time it works great, but then if you try to click the same link again, or even a link with a different # such as #2100 then it will no longer scroll to the id, once it has previously scrolled to an id.

I have read solutions to this issue, using a click event in javascript, however, how I don't think that that will work when sending out email notifications.

So the scenario is we email someone with a link https://www.domainhere.com/userprofile#1819 and the check it, but the next day we email a similar link with a different # such as https://www.domainhere.com/userprofile#1914 and when they arrive at the page, they don't move from the top of the page. Not sure why this is happening, or how to find a way around it. I've tried adding a unique ID, etc.

Anyone know how to make it so each time a user clicks these links in emails, they will arrive at the anchor? Even if they click the same link, perhaps because the first time they clicked the link in the email, they didn't have enough time to review the content, well once they visit that page, it doesn't matter what the # is, they stay at the top of the page.

The code is very simple. I am using "> as the anchor, and typing into the browser url the name of the page plus #numberhere - It works once, after that it doesn't work. Even if the number is different, ie. a new comment is emailed to the user.

I hope someone can help

Thanks

Comment: Ive only tested in Chrome. Maybe this is a Chrome issue. I will try other browsers now.

Comment: Testing on Edge, I find that it works each time I visit the page unless I hit refresh. If I hit refresh it doesnt scroll to the anchor.

Comment: One of the previous answers of the same sort of question suggests using javascript for a click event. 

document.location.href = "#";
document.location.href = "#myAnchor";

Could I possibly use this javascript as a page load event? I'm not sure how I would go about doing that, if that is even a solution for my issue. Thanks in advance anyone reading.